# Why is matplotlib just giving my points in a diagonal line?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

In Jupyter I wrote the following:

```
c357=np.loadtxt('/path/to/file.txt', dtype=str, delimiter=',')  
t357=np.loadtxt('/path/to/file.txt', dtype=str, delimiter=',')  
fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10)).  
ax.scatter(c357,t357)
```

[image: Plot of what code gives]

I have no idea why the axes aren't actually in order and if someone could help that would be great, thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [mre]. We need access to some sample data to determine what's going wrong.

Comment: Is your data in some kind of number format (float, int)?

Comment: Your data are text, not floats.

Comment: @BigBen How could I get the data in floats? When I try to do dtype=float I get the error could not convert string to float: ''

Comment: That's your problem? `''` can't be converted to a float. Maybe your data isn't what you think it is.

Comment: @BigBen Yeah you're right haha. There was a comma at the end of the .txt file and that's why it wouldn't allow it to be converted into a float. Thank you!